# Pydantic create_model_from_typeddict does not play nice with mypy?

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing, pydantic, python-3.10

I am using pydantic models generated from typeddicts in a project with mypy but I get a `invalid type` error when using one of those models as a return type.

This does not happend when directly using a BaseModel.

```py
from pydantic import create_model_from_typeddict
from typing import TypedDict


class TD_Foo(TypedDict):
    bar: int


M_Foo = create_model_from_typeddict(TD_Foo)

# error: Variable "pls.M_Foo" is not valid as a type  [valid-type]
def make_foo() -> M_Foo:
    return M_Foo(bar=42)


print(make_foo())
```

Is there an issue with my code or should I raise an issue ? Also if anyone knows if I should raise it on mypy or pydantic's repo ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at [the source](https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/blob/v1.10.2/pydantic/annotated_types.py#L22), it appears `create_model_from_typeddict` calls regular old `create_model` under the hood and passes along all `**kwargs` to it.

The function `create_model` *by default* always returns the type `Type[BaseModel]`. This is also how the return type of `create_model_from_typeddict` is annotated. Thus, it will definitely be correct in your case to annotate `make_foo` accordingly:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, create_model_from_typeddict
from typing import TypedDict


class TD_Foo(TypedDict):
    bar: int


M_Foo = create_model_from_typeddict(TD_Foo)


def make_foo() -> BaseModel:
    return M_Foo(bar=42)
```

No issues with `mypy`.

---

What I have an issue with, now that I am looking at this, is that `create_model_from_typeddict` doesn't mirror the overloaded annotations of `create_model` and thus the following causes a type error:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, create_model_from_typeddict                                                     from typing import TypedDict


class TD_Foo(TypedDict):
    bar: int


class FooModel(BaseModel):
    pass


M_Foo = create_model_from_typeddict(
    TD_Foo,
    __base__=FooModel,
)


def make_foo() -> FooModel:
    return M_Foo(bar=42)
```

Mypy correctly picks up the following:

```
20: error: Incompatible return value type (got "BaseModel", expected "FooModel")  [return-value]
```

Actually the type returned *indeed is* `FooModel` because `M_Foo` is in fact `Type[FooModel]`. This is, in my opinion, due to `create_model_from_typeddict` being wrongly (or incompletely) annotated. If passed a base class, the return type should be inferred accordingly, as it does with [`create_model`](https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/blob/v1.10.2/pydantic/main.py#L938).

I think I'll create a Pull Request for this, once I verify this is warranted.

---

Anyway, I hope this helps.

### PS

In case you are still wondering, why you can't just use `M_Foo` as an annotation, that is due to that class being dynamically created at runtime. It is just the old dilemma between static type checking and dynamic typing. Generally speaking, the type checker will not be able to handle such types.

Comment: Great answer thanks a lot !
I'll use BaseModel for now, hopefully some day we'll have something more practical for that.

Comment: This is a great answer. But I'm  bothered by the fact that when I do `create_model_from_typeddict(TD_Foo)`, mypy tells me that the TD_Foo object is not a TypedDict object, but a TD_Foo object. It doesnt fail, just marks it as wrong when its not. Is this related to the pull request that you proposed?